# Javascript Problems with Hide/Show Div containers

Tags: javascript

i've some Problems with following:

I don't get it how i compare the value of the checkbox with the classname of the div containers that i want to show/hide.

HTML:

```
            <div class="contShowLocations">
                <div class="tableHeaderWrapper">
                    <div class="tableHeadItemConfig" id="config" data-item="0">
                        <div class="tableHeadItemConfigSub">
                            <div class="tableHeadItemButton">
                                <button class="">
                                    <img src="src/icons/Gear.svg" width="20" alt="">
                                </button>                                
                            </div>
                            <div class="configSubContainer">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="" class="tableConfigAll" checked>ALL</label></li>
                                    <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="row-country" class="tableConfigCheckbox" checked>Country</label></li>
                                    <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="row-id" class="tableConfigCheckbox" checked>ID</label></li>
                                    <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="row-brand" class="tableConfigCheckbox" checked>Brand</label></li>
                                    <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="row-postal" class="tableConfigCheckbox" checked>Postal</label></li>
                                    <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="row-name" class="tableConfigCheckbox" checked>NAME</label></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>   
                    <div class="tableHeader">
                        <div class="tableHeadItem row-country row-selector showRow" id="row-country" data-item="1">LAND</div>
                        <div class="tableHeadItem row-id row-selector showRow" id="row-checkId" data-item="2">ID</div>
                        <div class="tableHeadItem row-brand row-selector showRow" id="row-brand" data-item="3">MARKE</div>
                        <div class="tableHeadItem row-postal row-selector showRow" id="row-postal" data-item="4">PLZ</div>
                        <div class="tableHeadItem row-name row-selector showRow" id="row-name" data-item="5">NAME</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tableContWrapper">
                    <div class="tableItem" data-order="1" id="row">
                        <div class="tableDataItem row-country row-selector showRow" id="row-country">Deutschland</div>
                        <div class="tableDataItem row-id row-selector showRow" id="row-checkId">B0015</div>
                        <div class="tableDataItem row-brand row-selector showRow" id="row-brand">Brand 1</div>
                        <div class="tableDataItem row-postal row-selector showRow" id="row-postal">12345</div>
                        <div class="tableDataItem row-name row-selector showRow" id="row-name">Name 1</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tableItem" data-order="2" id="row">
                        <div class="tableDataItem row-country row-selector showRow" id="row-country">Deutschland</div>
                        <div class="tableDataItem row-id row-selector showRow" id="row-checkId">B0015</div>
                        <div class="tableDataItem row-brand row-selector showRow" id="row-brand">Brand 2</div>
                        <div class="tableDataItem row-postal row-selector showRow" id="row-postal">13583</div>
                        <div class="tableDataItem row-name row-selector showRow" id="row-name">Name 2</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Javascript

```
let rowId = document.querySelectorAll('.row-selector');
let tableCheckBoxArray = [];
let tableRowArray = [];
let configCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.tableConfigCheckbox');

for(let configcheckbox of configCheckboxes) {
    configcheckbox.addEventListener('click', function(){

        if(this.checked == true) {   
          
            console.log("--- Check ---");
            console.log('Classname: ' + this.classList);
            console.log('Value: ' + this.value);
            rowId.forEach ( function(node, index, array){
                return node.classList;
            });
            let rid = Array.from(rowId);

            let rrid = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName(this.value));
            console.log("Contains: "+rrid.find(rid));
            if (this.value){
                console.log(this.value + ": gefunden");
                //rowId.style.display = 'block';       
            }
            else {
                console.log("nicht gefunden");
                //rowId.style.display = 'none';  
            }
  
        } else {
            console.log("--- Uncheck ---");           
            console.log('Classname: ' + this.classList);
            console.log('Value: ' + this.value);
        }    
        
    })
}
```

For example:
I try it with the `rid.contains(this.value)`. but recieve the message not a function.
That issue i got also with `.includes()`.

Thx :-)